# xcode UITests doesn't find header file in appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xctest

I'm having a XCTest UI bundle and when I want to run the tests it gives me this error:

```
AppDelegate.h:10:9: error: 'SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h' file not found
#import <SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD.h>
        ^
<unknown>:0: error: failed to import bridging header 'Supporting files/LZ-Bridging-Header.h'
```

The app itself runs so I don't see the problem. I'm using carthage for the dependencies so no cocoapods. I don't find anything on the internet related to this problem.

I've cleaned my derived data, clean build, clean, quite xcode. So I'm open for suggestions.

Can someone help me?

Comment: You can try hiding the header dependency by moving the header import into the `AppDelegate.m` file and add forward declarations to the `.h` file,  that should fix the bridging header issue.

Comment: Likely you need to add forward declarations for all classes used in the header file.

Comment: You are right. That fixes a lot of problem. I just have the same problem for some libraries that are in the .pch file. Do you know any solution for this too?

Comment: Hmm... are you somehow using the same bridging header for both the tested and the testing target?